# Object detection with multiple cameras | Prevent multiple detections of the same problem

Tags: opencv, camera, object-detection

I want to train a model to detect defects on products using object detection.
I am using 4 cameras in order to get a full 360 degree view of the object.

The problem that I have is that the camera FOVs are overlapping (and there isn't really a way for me to prevent this overlapping since the objects vary in width, depth, height and proxiity to different cameras).

This overlapping means that the model is detecting the same deffects in different cameras.

How could I prevent these duplicates ?

My current idea is to stitch the 4 images together (and somehow remove the overlapping parts) before actually applying the model. But the big problem that I have is that some deffects might still be in two different camera views.

Is there any spatial recognition API or something like that which could help me in this case ?

Comment: if your cameras are stationary and your product is stationary then you should define a region of interest for every camera. In my opinion stitching images is an unnecessarily complex solution.

Comment: @BarışAktaş, do you mean manually tuning where the camera should "look" at ?
If so, the problem I see with this is that since my objects can be of different sizes my ROI should change depending on the object..

Comment: turn the four views into one consistent view of the entire object. "stitching", as you suggested. if you do that right, no defect shows up twice. -- *show us your data*

Comment: @D.Gaulin If the need is to detect the defect not to measure or count it defining ROIs would be enough. If you add the cropped defect samples from the edges of the camera view to your training data your model could recognize them. Otherwise, stitching looks necessary you are right. Can you share some images?